# Are these capacitors parallel or in series?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-circuits, capacitance

I am a bit confused. The authors say these conductors are parallel when the switch is on. But to me it looks like they are in series since the handle is insulating. How can you explain that they are indeed parallel?
[image]

Comment: Trick question:  When only two components are connected to one another in a loop like that, you can call it "parallel" or you can call it "series", and you'd be right either way.

Comment: @jameslarge But that gives different values for say the charge in the capacitors? In series the charge would be the same but in parallel the capacitor with the higher capacity stores a higher charge.

Comment: You quoted part of an exercise from a textbook, but you left out the actual question.  I can only _guess_ that that you are supposed to calculate (A) the charge on each of the two capacitors, or (B) the final voltage, or both after the switch has been closed and the circuit reaches equilibrium.  In either case, calling it a "parallel" circuit would be a much more _useful_ model even though "series" technically is applicable.  Also, consider that there's a hidden third component---the voltmeter---which makes everything look a lot more parallel-y.

Comment: Also note, The exercise is not completely specified.  You can not predict the final state of the circuit after the switch is closed if you don't know the initial voltage across $C_2$.  The diagram doesn't say.  Probably you are supposed to _assume_ that the initial voltage is zero, and the neutral color highlight and lack of '+' and '-' signs on the $C_2$ symbol support that, but a lifetime's worth of experience has taught me to assume nothing, and question everything.

Answer (score 1):

If you argue that capacitors in parallel have the same p.d. across them and in series otherwise, then when the switch is thrown the capacitors are in series (the capacitors have different pd's) and the charged capacitor acts like a source of emf. After some finite time (assuming some finite residual resistance) afterwards the capacitors have the same pd so that they are then may be considered in parallel (if you argue that capacitors in parallel have the same pd). A reasonable argument is that components in series or parallel only have real meaning when part of some circuit involving a source of emf.

Answer (score 0):

simple answer: They are in parallel when both blades of the knife switch are closed. If only one blade was closed, the 2 capacitors would be in series between the 2 open points.